# how to hang 200lb chandelier?

Tags: ceiling, installation, load

I'm planning to buy crystal chandelier that weigh 200lb. We will be replacing existing chandelier in the two storied foyer (height 18 feet). Current chandelier is installed using electric metal box on 2x6 inch lumber installed between the joists. I have good access to attic and joists are 2x6 inch and spaced 16" apart. There is no other load on the joists (than the roof). Chandelier installation braces sold in stores and online are at the most rated for 150lb capacity. Questions i have:
1) Can I hang 200lb chandelier safely on 2x6 inch joists without causing damage to the joists (by overloading them) or to ceiling (because of joist deflection)? 
2) what type of hardware available for installing heavy chandelier - any link appreciated. 
3) seems like standard method of installing chandelier using electric box using screws may not be appropriate for 200lb chandelier - what technique should one employ to install heavy chandelier?
4) Is this something a DIYer can do it (i installed one chandelier in dining area) or are there more structural issues that I need to tackle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check with the manufacturer of the fixture. They should have some design parameters.
2. If they are modern day conventional residential roof trusses, I recommend contacting a mfg of same.  See what they say.
3. I personally would take a 3' piece of standard #2-and-better 4x6 lumber, free of flaws, lay it perpendicular across the top side of two trusses to use as your main support.  Drill and screw in place. 
   A standard 4-square metal box with a round mud ring will support the fixture.

Comment: I think an eye bolt clear thru the 4x6 with a nut and big washer on the top side would be more secure than a screw.

Comment: mud ring I saw in home depot has two screw opening to accept light fixture rectangle strip (with hole in middle that accepts threaded nipple) - but they are not rated anything higher than 60-80 lb range (screw opening is for really thin screws). May be I misunderstood  your  technique.

Comment: @wilk - so I connect metal electric box to the other end of eye bolt - but chandler would be connected to metal electric box using tradition method, right?

Comment: @bob - eye bolt has all of the weight, no wires.  metal box is just screwed into support.  No weight on the electric box.

Comment: I see. Chandelier connector assembly has threaded nipple (other end is hooked to the chain) so I need something that would connect chandelier threaded nipple and the eye hook, right? Is this something I can find in hardware store and what it is called?

Comment: Maybe add photo of that to your question?